# regex pattern to extract all the comma separated values altogether along with newline i.e. extract entire string

Tags: regex, regex-group, regex-greedy

Test String

```
Address: c8245A626
AliasName: eSrb002359_f1
Igroup Name: rtvclar002359, unjlclar002358-9,
cokeclar00RCB_FC
Protocol: REST
```

Note: "Igroup Name" field has 3 comma separated values and third value is in newline also.

Required output: `rtvclar002359, unjlclar002358-9, cokeclar00RCB_FC`

Regular Expression I have tried: `Igroup Name:\s+(.*)`

Answer (score 0):

`.` doesn't match newlines by default. `\s` will match any whitespace, which includes newline.

Try

```
Igroup Name:\s+((?:[\w-]+,\s*)*[\w-]+)
```

This matches any number (including 0) of values with `,` after them, followed by a single value with no comma. This will match all the values.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/IkWLWd/1)